# In AWS SQS, the "Start DLQ Redrive" button is disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Queue set up with a redrive policy that automatically sends failed messages to a Dead Letter Queue.  When looking at the Dead Letter Queue, there is a button to "start DLQ redrive" which should allow me to reprocess the failed messages in the original queue.  Unfortuately this button is not enabled on my queue and I cannot fiure out why.

relevant article here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-simple-queue-service-dead-letter-queue-redrive-to-source-queues/

Answer (score 4):

This button is not available for FIFO queues.

There is a note about this in the aws documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue-redrive.html

Comment: I was struggling with this all morning. After I read this I tested by creating both standard and fifo queues. And yup, you are correct, it only works standard queues. Thanks!

Comment: The linked doc page doesn't actually mention FIFO, although it does say "standard queue" a few times. Do you know if there is an alternative for FIFO queues if I want to redrive?

Comment: Rich, in AWS terminology, a "standard queue" is synonymous with "not FIFO".  You can see them use the term this way in their documentation for SQS's FIFO boolean option:  "If set to true, creates a FIFO queue. If you don't specify this property, Amazon SQS creates a standard queue."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#cfn-sqs-queue-fifoqueue